# NInject: Resolve constructor injection with two parameters

Tags: c#, ninject

I've created these interfaces and classes:

```
interface IInterpreter.
interface IViz.
interface IVizDescriptor.
```

where,

```
class IntOne : IInterpreter.
```

and,

```
class VizDescOne : IVizDescriptor {
    VizDescOne(string title, Type type, SchemaType schemaType, string desc)
    { }
}
```

and,

```
class VizOne : IViz {
    public VizOne (IntOne, IVizDescriptor)
    {
    }
}
```

I've figured out I'm able to create bindings between `IInterpreter` and `IntOne` in order to when I'm requesting for a `VizOne`, a `IntOne` is injected to the first parameter constructor.

The problem is that is there no way to create a suitable binding for `VizDescOne`. 
`VizDescOne`'s constructor parameters are too dependent of each situation I'm not able to create a binding for it.

Is there some way to provide it `manually` and resolve the `VizOne  (IntOne, IVizDescriptor)` constructor?

However, `IVizDescriptor` depends too much of any concrete situation

Comment: I expect that parameters like `title`, `type` and `desc` are runtime values; they are not constant during the lifetime of the application. [You should not abuse your container to inject runtime data into components](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99).

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of options:

1. You can bind IVizDescriptor to VizDescOne with constructor
   arguments:

   ```
   kernel.Bind<IVizDescriptor>().To<VizDescOne>()
         .WithConstructorArgument("title", "someTitle").WithConstructorArgument("type", typeof(int))...
   ```
2. You can bind IVizDescriptor to constant:

   ```
   IVizDescriptor vizDescOne = new VizDescOne(...);
   kernel.Bind<IVizDescriptor>().ToConstant(vizDescOne);
   ```
3. You can bind IVizDescriptor to method:

   ```
   kernel.Bind<IVizDescriptor>().ToMethod(o=> new VizDescOne(...));
   ```

You can read more about these options and a few more [here](https://lukewickstead.wordpress.com/2013/02/09/howto-ninject-part-1-basics/) and [here](https://lukewickstead.wordpress.com/2013/02/09/howto-ninject-part-2-advanced-features/).

As a side note I really suggest you to read @Steven comment and the article that he linked, because if the constructors parameters are do runtime values, you should reconsider your design.

Comment: (what) is kernel? The ninject docs seem to be rather elusive.